# Getting individual attribute values

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

```
<foo>
 <bar regname="version_v2" type="block_version_v2_t" num="1" addr="0x0" incr="0x4">text</bar>
</foo>
```

How can I get "version_v2", "block_version_v2_t", "0x0" individually using Python?

```
for reg in regfile.findall('reg'):
    name = reg.find('name').text
    type = reg[1].attrib
```

Comment: Can you provide the `xml` source file used by your program?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for regfile in root.findall('regfile'):
        for reg in regfile.findall('reg'):
            reg_type = reg.get('type')
            reg_addr = reg.get('addr')
```

By using get,we can get the values of the key in tag.